# How do I insert a regex quantifier into a range

Tags: regex

I have this regex range

```
/([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-#_~!$&'()*+,;=:]+)/
```

for the allowable characters for a user's username. I would like to add the @ char to the range but limit its quantity to 0 or 1 and have it's location be irrelevant.

I know @{0,1} is the quantifier syntax, but how do I combine it with my range to meet my specifications.

Requirements:

1. A - Z  alphabet
2. 0 - 9 numerals
3. Only 1 @ allowed
4. Special Characters: # - _ ~ ! $ & ' ( ) * + , ; = :

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a lookahead regex like this:

```
/^(?!(?:[^@]*@){2})[-a-zA-Z0-9.#_~!$&'()*+,;=:@]+$/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vC3rT8/3)

`(?!(?:[^@]*@){2})` will disallow 2 `@` in your input thus allowing you to use 0 or 1 `@` in input. Also check demo.

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

i would like to make you Regex small by using **\w** in it

here is what w indicates in regex

- **\w : Matches any word character (alphanumeric & underscore). Only matches low-ascii characters (no accented or non-roman characters). Equivalent to [A-Za-z0-9_]**

please look ahead for this,this will reduce length of your regex.

```js
^(?!(?:[^@\n]*@){2})[\w.#_~!$&'()*+,;=:@]+$
```

Answer (score -1):

Just copy your regex and add the `@` in the middle:

`/^([-a-zA-Z0-9.#_~!$&'*+,;=:()]+@?[-a-zA-Z0-9.#_~!$&'*+,;=:()]+)$/`

or more precisely:

`/^(@|@?[-a-zA-Z0-9.#_~!$&'*+,;=:()]+|[-a-zA-Z0-9.#_~!$&'*+,;=:()]+@|[-a-zA-Z0-9.#_~!$&'*+,;=:()]+@[-a-zA-Z0-9.#_~!$&'*+,;=:()]+)$/`

Comment: Your regex now as implicit minimum length of 2.

Comment: What's your minimum length of a username?

Comment: Please ask the author of the question.

Comment: My first comment is one reason. Another flaw I just discover is that your regex disallow `@` at the beginning or the end of the string, while the question explicitly states that `@` can be anywhere in the string, as long as it appears at most once

Comment: Yes, I'm sure you've found my entry in the edit logs.